# Nginx: Redirect a IP range to a file if it exists

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect users to a maintenance.php file if it exists, but not our internal address.
Now i got this working through if-statements, but these are considered evil within the location block..

This is the config now:

```
if (-f $document_root/maintenance.php) {
    return 503;
}

error_page 503 @maintenance;

location @maintenance {
    if ($ourips = 0) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php last;
    }
    if ($ourips = 1) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }
}

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(app|clear|maintenance)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

Any alternative way to do this without the two if-statements in location @maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, uses some if's but they shouldn't be evil in this context as far as i'm aware..

```
    if (-f $document_root/maintenance.php) {
            set $test A;
    }
    if ($ourips = 0) {
            set $test "${test}B";
    }
    if ($test = AB) {
            return 503;
    }

    error_page 503 @maintenance;

    location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php last;
    }
    location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
    location @rewriteapp {
            # rewrite all to app.php
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }
    location ~ ^/(app|clear|maintenance)\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
```

nginx.conf

```
    geo $ourips {
      default 0;
      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1;
    }
```